# Collect postgres numeric NaN values as NaN/NA in R?

Tags: r, postgresql, dplyr, rpostgresql

I am having an issue getting NaN numeric data with `dplyr` (0.5.0) from a PostgreSQL column of type numeric (and thus supports NaN). The underlying fault is in `RPostgreSQL`, which reads `NaN` values as zero. E.g.:

```
# create table
create table tmp_dplyr_NaN_test_20170802 (
val numeric
);

insert into tmp_dplyr_NaN_test_20170802 (val) values (100);
insert into tmp_dplyr_NaN_test_20170802 (val) values ('NaN');
```

Then, running `select * from tmp_dplyr_NaN_test_20170802;` returns the values `100, NaN` as expected.

In `R`:

```
RPostgreSQL::dbGetQuery(con, "select val from tmp_dplyr_NaN_test_20170802")
# val
# 1 100
# 2   0
```

which can be 'fixed' by:

```
RPostgreSQL::dbGetQuery(con, "select nullif(val, 'NaN') from tmp_dplyr_NaN_test_20170802")

#     nullif
# 1    100
# 2     NA
```

I am wondering what is going on under the hood here. How does one actually collect `NaN` values as `NaN` or `NA` without resorting to `nullif` inside the database?